# task queue on redis cluster

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

I have a setup with single Redis node and I use a list to push and consume tasks through various clients connected to this single Redis node.

I want to move this setup to Redis cluster eventually. Should the task queue/list which is present in the above setup be split across all the nodes of Redis cluster or should it fit in only one of the hash slots or in other words in one of the redis nodes in the cluster.

Comment: I have similar question but i guess no one here knows/wants to answer